# Selecting common value of one column for array elements of another column

Tags: mysql, sql

Am having the following table structure,

```
--------------------------------------------------------
| id   |   po_bill_details_id   |   po_id   |   status |
--------------------------------------------------------
| 1    |   18                   |   6       |   1      |
| 2    |   16                   |   7       |   1      |
| 3    |   18                   |   7       |   1      |
--------------------------------------------------------
```

I need to select po_bill_details_id, which will be a common value for the given array of po_id. i.e. If i give [6,7] as input for po_id, i should only get 18 from po_bill_details_id and not 16. How can i query to MySQL for this logic?

Comment: So you want to get bill id which has corresponding PO id as per entire input array. Interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try ::

```
select 
po_bill_details_id

from table

where po_id in (/*your array*/)

group by po_bill_details_id having count(po_id)=(/*your array's length*/)
```

Comment: That should be `having count(po_id) > 1`, no? I think the OP wants results that are duplicates once the table has been filtered by the predicates.

Comment: @Asad: You have answered to a a specific example OP has provided, the OP needed those duplicate values which are common to all po_id

Comment: `the OP needed those duplicate values which are common to all po_id` this is the part I'm having trouble understanding. By the way, `po_bills_id` isn't a column.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following. I am on mobile, so can't test out though. Based on the number of elements in array you can change the count.

```
SELECT bill_id FROM yourtable
WHERE PO_id IN (7,6) 
GROUP BY bill_d 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT po_id) = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT po_bill_details_id
FROM   <table>
WHERE  po_id IN ( 6, 7 )
HAVING COUNT(po_bill_details_id) > 1
```

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean

```
select distinct po_bill_details_id from YOUR_TABLE where po_id=6 or po_id=7;
```